# Meilisearch index not being created

Tags: node.js, meilisearch

I have been using Meilisearch for a couple of months and have recently upgraded to 0.26.0. For some reason, when I am today trying to create an index using the node package, nothing seems to happen.

I can successfully use the `createIndex` method like below:

```
client.createIndex("movies")
```

and the return value for the method shows the task:

```
{
   uid: 26858,
   indexUid: 'movies',
   status: 'enqueued',
   type: 'indexCreation',
   enqueuedAt: '2022-04-08T15:15:06.325108519Z'
}
```

However, when I look up this task it seems that it has not been started:

```
{
  uid: 26858,
  indexUid: 'movies',
  status: 'enqueued',
  type: 'indexCreation',
  details: { primaryKey: null },
  duration: null,
  enqueuedAt: '2022-04-08T15:15:06.325108519Z',
  startedAt: null,
  finishedAt: null
}
```

And indeed I can't find the index using the `getIndexes` method.

Strangely I created an index without issue just a few days ago.

Any idea what the issue might be or how I could debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of Meilisearch's asynchronous operations belong to a category called "tasks". **Create an index is one of them**.

Depending on the queue size and server processing power it may take a while to process  recently created tasks.

You can find more information on section [asynchronous operation](https://docs.meilisearch.com/learn/advanced/asynchronous_operations.html) of documentation.

Comment: Is there a way to delete/stop some tasks from the meilisearch task queue?

Comment: Unfortunately there are not a way to delete/stop the tasks.